# Binary SMS receiving on Android: dynamic receiver registration

Tags: android, binary, sms, intentfilter

I can send and receive data SMS on Android using the following code snippets:

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) PORT, data,piSend, piDelivered);
```

where PORT=8091 for the sender. And for the receiver, a broadcast intent is defined in the manifest file as follows:

```
 <receiver android:name=".DataSMSReceiver"> 
 <intent-filter> 
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
 <data android:port="8091"/>
 <data android:scheme="sms"/> 
 </intent-filter> 
 </receiver>
```

then received in the DataSMSReceiver class.

However, I need to register the broadcast receiver dynamically as I do for text SMS e.g.:

```
protected static final String SMS_RECEIVED="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED));
```

How can I specify the port in the IntentFilter to register the receiver dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use [`addDataAuthority(String, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addDataAuthority%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). For example:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECIEVED);
filter.addDataAuthority("*", "8091");
filter.addDataScheme("sms");

//use the filter, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't find it easily, I post it here:

the String 
`"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`
can be found as constant in the [`Telephony.Sms.Intents`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html) class as:

`Telephony.Sms.Intents.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`